# I want to make a earth globe which zooms in with react-three-fiber

Tags: javascript, reactjs, camera, zooming, react-three-fiber

I am making a globe that is in a canvas. I want to zoom towards the globe from far somewhere.

Eg: Globe's position is at [0,0,0] and camera is at [0,0,100] now I want when the page loads the camera zooms towards it slowly creating nice animation.

I have wrote this much amount of code:

```
import './App.css';
import {Canvas} from '@react-three/fiber'
import {OrbitControls} from '@react-three/drei'
import Earth from './models/Earth'
import {Suspense,useState} from 'react'
function App() {
  
  return (
    <Canvas concurrent
    colorManagement style={{backgroundColor:"black",height:"100vh",width:"100vw"}}
     orthographic camera={{ zoom: 1, position: [0, 0, 25] }}
    >
    <ambientLight intensity={0.5} />
    <OrbitControls />
    <Suspense fallback={null} ><Earth size={0.1} /></Suspense>
</Canvas>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Main question is how to change zoom dynamically when page loads?

Answer (score 2):

This is practically inbuilt into React, suspense can do it. https://twitter.com/0xca0a/status/1402558012519337989

```
<Suspense fallback={null}>
  <ComponentThatLoadsModel />
  <Zoom />
</Suspense>

function Zoom() {
  return useFrame(state => state.camera......
```

The zoom component will mount once everything in the suspense block has been loaded, that makes it trivial to execute an action afterwards. You simply drop the zoom component in.

Here's an example that does it: https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-newton-k7f9x?file=/src/App.tsx